# PaddingFIFOQueue.enqueue_many throwing Value Error: Shapes must be equal rank

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have an RNN model, to which I'm trying to feed in varying length input sequences  through input pipelines randomly sampling from multiple TF record files containing serialized SequenceExamples, batch padding and shuffling across multiple batches

each sequence example has 3 elements, as  length: constant, input:1-D array, labels:1-D array

Procedure is as follows

```
def read_file_queue(self,filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    key, ex = reader.read(filename_queue)
    context_features = {
        "seq-len": tf.FixedLenFeature([],dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    sequence_features = {
        "tokens": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([],dtype=tf.int64),
        "labels": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([],dtype=tf.int64)
    }

    context_parsed, sequence_parsed = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(serialized=ex,
                                                                       context_features=context_features,
                                                                       sequence_features=sequence_features)
    return context_parsed["seq-len"], sequence_parsed["tokens"],sequence_parsed["labels"]

def get_batch_data(self):
    fqueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(self.data_filelist,
                                            shuffle=True,
                                            num_epochs=self.num_epochs)

    # read from multiple tf records as defined by read_threads
    ex = [self.read_file_fmt(fqueue) for _ in range(self.read_threads)]
    print(ex)
    # ex = self.read_file_fmt(fqueue)
    pad_output = self.padding_pipeline(ex)
    shuffle_output = self.shuffle_pipeline(pad_output)
    return shuffle_output

def padding_pipeline(self, input):
    padding_queue = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(
        capacity=self.pad_capacity,
        dtypes=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64],
        shapes=[[], [None], [None]])

    # use enqueue_many instead enqueue because 
    # the input is list of tuples from each tf record reader thread

    padding_enqueue_op = padding_queue.enqueue_many(input) # <<< !!!!! error here !!!!!
    padding_queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(padding_queue, [padding_enqueue_op] * self.pad_threads)
    tf.train.add_queue_runner(padding_queue_runner)
    padding_dequeue_op = padding_queue.dequeue_up_to(self.batch_size)
    return padding_dequeue_op

def shuffle_pipeline(self,input):
    shuffle_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(
        capacity=self.shuffle_capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=self.shuffle_min_after_dequeue,
        dtypes=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64],
        shapes=None)
    shuffle_enqueue_op = shuffle_queue.enqueue(input)
    shuffle_queue_runner = tf.train.QueueRunner(
        shuffle_queue, [shuffle_enqueue_op] * self.shuffle_threads)
    tf.train.add_queue_runner(shuffle_queue_runner)
    shuffle_dequeue_op = shuffle_queue.dequeue()
    return shuffle_dequeue_op
```

For which I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1    From merging
>   shape 0 with other shapes. for
>   'padding_fifo_queue_EnqueueMany/component_0' (op: 'Pack') with input
>   shapes: [], [?], [?].

I'm sure I'm doing something silly here, however, I could not find what is that im doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Taking a hint from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44019799/1861627), maybe you should have the following?

```
padding_queue = tf.PaddingFIFOQueue(
        capacity=self.pad_capacity,
        dtypes=[tf.int64, tf.int64, tf.int64],
        shapes=[None, [None], [None]])
```

By the way, if you could add some basic script for generating random data in the format you are using, it would be easier to replicate. Thanks.