# Contrastive Loss Function apply on siamese network and something wrong with optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've built a Siamese network for practice, I've checked some example on the site, but when I try to run the code it shows some error, I have no idea if there is a problem with the dimension. Hope someone could help and teach me.

```
batch_size = 32
epoch = 50
kernel_size = (3,3)
pooling_size = (2,2)
learning_rate = 0.001
margin_siamese = 1


siamese_nn = tf.Graph()
with siamese_nn.as_default():

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    anchor_img = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28, 1], name = 'anchor_image')
    compare_img = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 28, 28, 1], name = 'compare_image')
    Y_label = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None, 1], name = 'Y_label')
    learning_rate = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [1])

with tf.variable_scope('siamese_net'):
    conv_s1_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(anchor_img, filters= 64, kernel_size= kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_1')
    conv_s1_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s1_1, pool_size= pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_1')

    conv_s1_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_s1_1, filters = 32, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_2')
    conv_s1_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s1_2, pool_size = pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_2')

    conv_s1_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_s1_2, filters = 16, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_3')
    conv_s1_3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s1_3, pool_size = pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_3')

    anchor_vector = tf.layers.flatten(conv_s1_3, name = 'flatten')

with tf.variable_scope('siamese_net', reuse= True):

    conv_s2_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(compare_img, filters= 64, kernel_size= kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_1')
    conv_s2_1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s2_1, pool_size= pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_1')

    conv_s2_2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_s2_1, filters = 32, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_2')
    conv_s2_2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s2_2, pool_size = pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_2')

    conv_s2_3 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv_s2_2, filters = 16, kernel_size = kernel_size, activation= tf.nn.relu, name= 'siamese_3')
    conv_s2_3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv_s2_3, pool_size = pooling_size, strides = (1,1), name= 'siamese_3')

    compare_vector = tf.layers.flatten(conv_s2_3, name = 'flatten')


with tf.name_scope('loss_function'):
    loss = tf.contrib.losses.metric_learning.contrastive_loss(Y_label, anchor_vector, compare_vector)

with tf.name_scope('training'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
    optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

#### Error msg

```
Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'training/Adam/update_siamese_net/siamese_1/kernel/ApplyAdam' (op: 'ApplyAdam') with input shapes: [3,3,1,64], [3,3,1,64], [3,3,1,64], [], [], [1], [], [], [], [3,3,1,64].
```

Comment: The solution to this problem is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019515/valueerror-in-mulit-task-network-shape-must-be-rank-0-but-is-rank-1

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning giser_yugang's answer below for the benefit of the community.

Learning Rate is declared as a 1D Tensor while it should be a scalar.

So, changing the line of code,

`learning_rate = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [1])` to

`learning_rate = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [])` will resolve the error.